# マルチスレッドの変数のスコープについて

Tags: java

お世話になります。
表題の件ですが、javaのマルチスレッド環境下にて
new ArrayList()のインスタンス変数を使用したため、ConcurrentModificationExceptionが発生しました。
そして、メソッド内の変数にnew ArrayList()を使用すればローカル変数となるので、スレッドセーフになると伺いました。
そこでなのですが、ArrayListは非同期のクラスですが、それでもメソッド内であればスレッドセーフの変数としてしようできるのでしょうか。お教えください

Answer (score 2):

**短い答え**：`ArrayList`は本質的にスレッドセーフではありません。スレッドセーフなListが必要な場合は、`Collections.synchronizedList`を利用してください。

```
List<X> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

---

> メソッド内の変数にnew ArrayList()を使用すればローカル変数となるので、スレッドセーフになると伺いました。

誤りです。変数のスコープと、スレッドセーフには何の相関もありません。スレッドセーフか否かは、該当クラスやメソッドの外部仕様として決まっている性質です。

> ArrayListは非同期のクラスですが、それでもメソッド内であればスレッドセーフの変数としてしようできるのでしょうか。

いいえ。ただし、あるインスタンスがメソッド内ローカル変数からしか参照されないのであれば、他スレッドから操作できませんから、結果的に事故が起きないというだけです。

Comment: yohjpさん
丁寧な説明ありがとうございます。
下記ご教授頂きましたようにメソッド内でArrayListにaddしているだけですので結果的に
他のスレッドから編集できない状況になっているかと思います（テストでは同時実行してConcurrentModificationExceptionが発生しなかったですが、精度的に不安がありましたので）。いろいろなサイトを見ましたが、確かな答えがえられなかったです。どうもありがとうございます。
＞あるインスタンスがメソッド内ローカル変数からしか参照されないのであれば、他スレッドから操作できませんから、結果的に事故が起きないというだけです。